# How to remove table row if the form any of the input or select was empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form as below, Here i am looking to remove tr row if the input text and select option was empty. and the show the table row if any of the input was not empty

As you can see the input was not empty, it was removing the entire row, it is possible check both are not empty then remove

By using Jquery

Note: table rows are dynamically adding

```js
$(function(){
$("table#my_form tr td").each(function(){
  $(this).find('input, select').each(function(){
      if($(this).val()==""){
        $(this).closest('tr.table_row').remove();
      }
  })
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="">

<table id="my_form">
    <tr class="table_row">
       <td>
            <input type="text" name="company" value="TCS" />
        </td>
        <td>
         <select name="favorites" id="favorites">
          <option value="">Select Favorites</option>
          <option value="chess">Chess</option>
          <option value="caroms" selected>Caroms</option>
          <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
         </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="table_row">
       <td>
            <input type="text" name="company" value="Deloite" />
        </td>
        <td>
         <select name="favorites" id="favorites">
          <option value="">Select Favorites</option>
          <option value="chess">Chess</option>
          <option value="caroms">Caroms</option>
          <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
         </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="table_row">
       <td>
            <input type="text" name="company" value="GOOGLE" />
        </td>
        <td>
         <select name="favorites" id="favorites">
          <option value="">Select Favorites</option>
          <option value="chess" selected>Chess</option>
          <option value="caroms">Caroms</option>
          <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
         </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: curious, i'm not aware of the complete context here, so this may not apply.  But, why focus on removing a row - why not only add a row if the **input** is valid?

Comment: What triggers the removal of rows if you are adding them dynamically?  Your posted code would only run once when the page is loaded.

Comment: Do you want to remove the row when the input changes? Then you should put the removing code into e.g. `$(this).find('input, select').change(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check all inputs, you could try something like this.  As you mentioned, you are adding rows dynamically, so you would want some other event handler to check again for more bad rows. This code would run once on page load, and then again any time the **'#removeBadRows'** button is clicked.

```js
$(function () {
    removeBadRows();

    $(document).on('click', '#removeBadRows', function () {
        removeBadRows();
    });
});

function removeBadRows() {
    $("table#my_form tr").each(function () {
        var badCount = 0;
        var inputLength = $(this).find('input, select').length;
        $(this).find('input, select').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                badCount++;
            }
        });
        if (badCount == inputLength) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="">

    <table id="my_form">
        <tr class="table_row">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="company" value="test" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="favorites" id="favorites">
                    <option value="">Select Favorites</option>
                    <option value="chess">Chess</option>
                    <option value="caroms" selected>Caroms</option>
                    <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table_row">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="company" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="favorites" id="favorites">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Favorites</option>
                    <option value="chess">Chess</option>
                    <option value="caroms">Caroms</option>
                    <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table_row">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="company" value="GOOGLE" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="favorites" id="favorites">
                    <option value="">Select Favorites</option>
                    <option value="chess">Chess</option>
                    <option value="caroms">Caroms</option>
                    <option value="ruby" selected>Ruby</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Nicolay, i have second input was not empty, but it was removing the row

Comment: The logic is pretty straight forward, do you have any hidden inputs inside the table row it might be finding?

Comment: I have no other inputs, Pls check your code in fiddle

Comment: Edited my post with snippet, working as expected for me, according to the logic, row  2 should be removed because it has no value in the select, row 1 and 3 are good.

Comment: But the input was not empty, You have check both the input. There is no difference between your code and my code

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, I thought you wanted to see if ANY input in the table row was empty (1 or many) if so = hide.  Are you saying the opposite? If 1 or many fields DOES HAVE a value, you want to keep it?

Comment: Ok, check my edits, I added a variable to get the number of fields in the table row, if the number of empty fields equals the number of fields (no matter how many) it should now remove the row.

Comment: Perfect, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This could be the most simple method

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('change', '.table_row input', function(e) {
    if($(this).val()==""){
      $(this).closest('.table_row').remove();
    }
  });
});
```